# Download all files attached on a site

Tags: files

I have researched a little bit and I haven't found a sound solution to downloading all attached files from all content types across an entire site in an single action. I have found a couple modules like Backup & Migrate, or its plugin Backup & Migrate Files that perform similar functions, but nothing to effect that I need. I am trying to archive all attached files for a schools site. The site is drupal7.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire `files` directory of uploaded files, you can do this with Drush:

```
drush rsync @source.target:%files/ @destination.target:%files
```

See: https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/core/core-rsync/

This relies on having `%files` defined in your `path-alias` part of your alias definitions for drush.

Alternatively, you could ssh into the server, and tar/gzip the files directory, then scp it down to your machine (or sftp/ftp, I suppose).

Either of these methods will bring the entire files directory with it, which will have all uploaded files, any image derivatives (generated image style files) as well as cached css/js files. If you use the drush command with arguments, you can exclude directories you don't want.